# Downloading a webpage in C# example

Tags: c#, stream

I am trying to understand some example code on this web page: (http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx) that downloads a file from the internet.

The piece of code quoted below goes through a loop getting chunks of data and saving them to a string until all the data has been downloaded. As I understand it, "count" contains the size of the downloaded chunk and the loop runs until count is 0 (an empty chunk of data is downloaded).

My question is, isn't it possible that count could be 0 without the file being completely downloaded? Say if the network connection is interrupted, the stream may not have any data to read on a pass of the loop and count should be 0, ending the download prematurely. Or does ResStream.Read stop the program until it gets data? Is this the correct way to save a stream?

```
    int count = 0;

      do
      {
       // fill the buffer with data
       count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

       // make sure we read some data
       if (count != 0)
       {
        // translate from bytes to ASCII text
        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

        // continue building the string
        sb.Append(tempString);
       }
      }
      while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
```

Comment: MSDN shows an identical sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Stream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) will only return `0` once the end of the stream has been reached. The `Read` call will block until there is data available or the connection has been closed.

The code will work as it is, but could be simplified:

```
int count;

while ((count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
{
    // translate from bytes to ASCII text
    string tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

    // continue building the string
    sb.Append(tempString);
}
```